# Get show create table query without indexes in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on exporting a SQL file using PHP.

When I use this query "SHOW CREATE TABLE users"

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Active','Inactive') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `verification_status` enum('No','Pending','Verified','Resubmit') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_fb_id_unique` (`fb_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10012 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I get "duplicate entry '' for key 'users_fb_id_unique" when importing
so I need a query for a table structure without index fields and primary key like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Active','Inactive') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `verification_status` enum('No','Pending','Verified','Resubmit') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: If you want to replace existing contents ignoring/replace rows with duplicate entry errors, may `INSERT IGNORE` or `REPLACE` is the SQL you need. Dropping indexes just should like pain for later.

Comment: hi @danblack i am not going to drop indexes, i will write a code after insert 'users' table data

Comment: An option is to disable foreign key checks before executing the query with `SET_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` then re-enable it after the query with `SET_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1` if you're comfortable with it.

Comment: **Your code is wrong.** 1) Excess comma after ```UNIQUE KEY `users_fb_id_unique` (`fb_id`),``` 2) No `fb_id` column in the structure.